# WooCommerce free shipping twice a week

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a Woocommerce store and I want to Free shipping (on all products) but only twice a week. The days can be defined (like Tuesday and Wednesday).

So, free shipping should be applied on Tuesday and Wednesday only.

Comment: OK. I don't know WooCommerce well enough: do you need help setting up free shipping, or turning it on and off automatically on certain days, or something else?

Comment: Yes. I want to enable free shipping on certain days.

Comment: I think I figured this out. I have used the solution shared here - https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/3b442n/woocommerce_free_shipping_on_certain_days/

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Girish. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as Woocommerce) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I would suggest getting started with your plugin for this feature and then ask specific questions as they arise as it is much easier for experts to give quick advice when you can show what you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you. will keep this in mind

Comment: There is an answer on StackOverFlow: [Make free shipping available on specific days of the week in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886761/make-free-shipping-available-on-specific-days-of-the-week-in-woocommerce/57889514#57889514)